# Hazelcast and Payara 5 - Tries to close entityManager if hazelcast is used in a transactional context

Tags: java, hazelcast, payara

we are currently trying to use Hazelcast in our Jakarta EE 8 Application running on Payara 5.2022.x.
We have huge problems when trying to access IMap instances when using hazelcast in any method that is even remotely in a transactional context.
The problem seems to be that the Payara Tenant that is user in combination with Hazelcast tries to tear down everything after each and every access to the Hazelcast Map.
This fails nearly 100% of the time resulting in this Stack:

```
 [2023-08-18T08:42:24.310+0200] [Payara 5.2022.2] [SCHWERWIEGEND] [] [com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=72 _ThreadName=hz.priceless_meitner.partition-operation.thread-9] [timeMillis: 1692340944310] [levelValue: 1000] [[
 [192.168.100.70]:4900 [development] [4.2] Failed to process: com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PutOperation{serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', identityHash=353117872, partitionId=105, replicaIndex=0, callId=-1914, invocationTime=1692340944309 (2023-08-18 08:42:24.309), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000, tenantControl=fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.PayaraHazelcastTenant@30695580, name=statefulRoomSOSChangeListenerMap} on: hz.priceless_meitner.partition-operation.thread-9
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManager.
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.verifyOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:2067)
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:1908)
   at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper$NonTxEMCleaner.beforePostInvoke(EntityManagerWrapper.java:1241)
   at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl$ListComponentInvocationHandler.lambda$beforePostInvoke$2(InvocationManagerImpl.java:430)
   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
   at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl$ListComponentInvocationHandler.beforePostInvoke(InvocationManagerImpl.java:430)
   at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.postInvoke(InvocationManagerImpl.java:198)
   at fish.payara.appserver.context.ContextImpl$Context.close(ContextImpl.java:61)
   at fish.payara.appserver.context.ContextImpl$RequestContext.close(ContextImpl.java:126)
   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.Operation.popThreadContext(Operation.java:822)
   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:258)
   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:213)
   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:175)
   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:139)
   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123)
   at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)
]]
```

In many instances I was able to mitigate the problem by switching from
`javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedScheduledExecutorService` to using regular `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`.
Sometimes I was able to annotate the enclosing method with `@Transactional(TxType.NOT_SUPPORTED)`.

But this can't be the correct way. There must be a way to use Hazelcast in Payara without avoiding every bit of transactional container magic.

Every bit of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The same here with Payara 5.2022.5. JCache fails nearly all the time when requesting (more precisely, when performing then get opration of hazelcast). As of my research it, it was introduced into Payara when they switched to Hazelcast 4.2.* implementation after Payara 5.2021.2.

Comment: Maybe we can share some ideas or experiences about this problem?

Comment: My very anoying and unsatisfying work around is to move every operation that interacts with the hazelcast map to a seperate thread which is not managed by the container, either by starting the Thread manually with new Thread(()-> hazelcastMap.put()).start(); or by using a non managed Executor from Executos.newCachedThreadPool();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).